# req.body undefined (post)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Client :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  gcm := GetGCMInstance;
  p := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  p.Items[0] := StringToJString('460004329921');
  FRegistrationID := JStringToString(gcm.register(p));
  FAlreadyRegistered := (FRegistrationID <> '');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(BooltoStr(FAlreadyRegistered));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(FRegistrationID);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Edit1.Text);
  req.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  req.AddParameter('tableName', 'users', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  req.AddParameter('regid', FRegistrationID, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  req.AddParameter('email', Edit1.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
  req.Execute;
  jsonValue:= res.JSONValue;
  X := SO(jsonValue.ToString);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(X['results'].AsString);
end;

function TForm1.GetGCMInstance: JGoogleCloudMessaging;
begin
  result := TJGoogleCloudMessaging.JavaClass.getInstance(SharedActivity.getApplicationContext);
end;
```

Node.js Server:

```
var nodePort = 3030;
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var db = require('mysql');
var dbPool = db.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '1234',
    database : 'test',
    port : 3306
});

var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var message = new gcm.Message();
var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyChp2jTQsgPkLaaVgFh6yoovu1Td7tuQMo'); //Api Key
var registrationIds = [];
registrationIds.push('APA91bGNYh3cIL0jcWAhfTIhTen-ThNQRrSbAJ30UEV7I93ejL0BgWok1VU45xs8p82KKcMj5-7SUXf65UCkNa6rVTJ0nYqwEx0Jv7zezaCvQnrQikKjnJGTXHCQEWXhtTOaeXR__7qQYPV5BudtA_0Thty4itfz5Q');
registrationIds.push('APA91bFQX8NJ4goolOGdA-U_MxtwKLk1wMLYMddXV2FetT4A7z3d_ZPYSRz1lkXWo-6QoYgOR4xYD8WeBwFDGqpuZbiBgYV_1H8JPtdPzKGXRQr5jiMD_C5nntxeWNb0aBIi-ejTGo881S8NWvC4K_u28DlZG47ecQ');

app.use( bodyParser.json() );

app.post('/api/db', function(req, res){
    if(!req.body.tableName){
        var data = {
            ID : req.body.id,
            Name : req.body.name
        }
        tableName = 'person';
    }else{
        var data = {
            email : req.body.email,
            regid : req.body.regid
        }
        tableName = 'users';
    }//else
    console.log(req.body);
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    dbPool.getConnection(function(objErr, objConn){
        if(objErr){
            sendError(res, 503, 'error', 'connection', objErr); //503 - Service Unavailable
        }else{
            objConn.query("INSERT INTO "+tableName+" SET ? ", data, function(Err, Rows, Fields){
                if(Err){
                    sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
                }else{
                    res.send({
                        results : 'success'
                    });
                    objConn.release();
                    if(!req.body.tableName){ gcmSend(); }
                }//else
            });
        }//else
    });
});
```

Client side got registrationid but nodejs console.log(req.body); -> {} (undefined)
I tried to with get method, it works but post does not work. req.body couldnt handle variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you forgot to parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, Please include following line in server.js file and try once.

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

[Resource.](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser)

Comment: Great. Keep going. :)